# Await message in flutter waiting woocommerce rest api

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, flutter, woocommerce

i use woocommerce rest api with flutter to get product variations.
Woocommerce rest api is too slowly to get this variations.
I need to send a message to the user to wait for the process to finish.
How to put this message in the code?

```
     @override
  Future<List<ProductVariation>> getProductVariations(Product product,
      {String lang = 'en'}) async {
    try {
      final List<ProductVariation> list = [];
      int page = 1;

      while (true) {
        String endPoint =
            "products/${product.id}/variations?per_page=100&page=$page";
        if (kAdvanceConfig["isMultiLanguages"]) {
          endPoint += "&lang=$lang";
        }

        var response = await wcApi.getAsync(endPoint);
        if (response is Map && isNotBlank(response["message"])) {
          throw Exception(response["message"]);
        } else {
          if (response is List && response.isEmpty) {
            /// No more data.
            break;
          }
          for (var item in response) {
            if (item['visible']) {
              list.add(ProductVariation.fromJson(item));
            }
          }

          /// Fetch next page.
          page++;
        }
      }

      return list;
    } catch (e) {
      //This error exception is about your Rest API is not config correctly so that not return the correct JSON format, please double check the document from this link https://docs.inspireui.com/fluxstore/woocommerce-setup/
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Any help?

Comment: Just want to confirm. You want some kind of a toast or loading widget to inform user that request is still ongoing?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this small example:

```
class Waitscreen extends StatefulWidget {
      Waitscreen ({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _WaitscreenState createState() => _WaitscreenState();
    }
    
    class _WaitscreenState extends State<Waitscreen> {
      bool _isLoading = false;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text(_isLoading ? "Loading..." : "Load"),
          onPressed: () async {
            setState((){_isLoading = !_isLoading;});
            // TODO
            await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)); // await getProductVariations...
            // TODO
            setState((){_isLoading = !_isLoading;});
        }
        ),
      ),
    );
   } 
 }
```

> Then you can do something like, according to your need!

Comment: Thank you! But i dont have idea howto implement this solution. Im newbie on flutter

Comment: Take a look here https://www.clounce.com/flutter/loading-screen-in-flutter

Comment: @Jhakiz Please do not add a link to the OP's account on all of your posts. It adds unnecessary clutter.